# Add Images to Random Div Function

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I am looking to add a function to the code below... Currently, the code takes an image from a single source and randomly places the images all around the web page.

I would like any help with modifying the code so that it uses images from a directory of photos that I have. I would like to use all of the photos from the directory individually, and not just a singular photo. :)

Let me know if you might know how to do this.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

</head>
<body>
    <div class="random">img 1</div>
    <div class="random">img 2</div>
    <div class="random">img 3</div>
    <div class="random">img 4</div>
    <div class="random">img 5</div>
    <div class="random">img 6</div>
    <div class="random">img 7</div>
    <div class="random">img 8</div>
    <div class="random">img 9</div>
    <div class="random">img 10</div>
    <div class="random">img 11</div>
    <div class="random">img 12</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.random {
  position: absolute;
  width: 128px;
  height: 160px;
}
```

JS:

```
const imgPoss = [];

let maxX, maxY;

function placeImg() {
    const NUM_OF_IMAGES = 90; // set this to however images you have in the directory.
    const randImg = Math.random() * NUM_OF_IMAGES;
    const imgSrc = 'https://elimcgehee.github.io/staticimages/gallery/' + randImg.toString() + '.png';

    const {random: r} = Math;  
    const x = r() * maxX;
    const y = r() * maxY;
    
    if(!isOverlap(x,y)) {
        var link = `<img class="random" style="left: ${x}px; top: ${y}px;" src="${imgSrc}" />`;
        var bodyHtml = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = bodyHtml + link;
        
        imgPoss.push({x, y}); // record all img positions
    }
}

function isOverlap(x, y) { // return true if overlapping
    const img = {x: 128, y:160};
    
    for(const imgPos of imgPoss) {
        if( x>imgPos.x-img.x && x<imgPos.x+img.x &&
            y>imgPos.y-img.y && y<imgPos.y+img.y ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

onload = function() {
    maxX = innerWidth - 128;
    maxY = innerHeight - 160;
    setInterval(placeImg, 10);
}

onresize = function() {
    maxX = innerWidth - 128;
    maxY = innerHeight - 160;
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting question, however I'm not sure you can easily read a file directory client-side without user interaction (i.e. uploading files). See [MDN File and Directory API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API) for inspo! Alternatively, you could try running a js webserver with Node.

Comment: do you have any kind of backend language like PHP to assist?